# Unable to download PDF attachment with java by using JavaMail

Tags: java, pdf, imap, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am creating Email client using JavaMail API. Everything is working fine like I am able to connect to mail server(using IMAP), Delete mail,  retrieving received mails and displaying them to user etc.

Now problem comes when it comes to download "PDF Attachments". PDF files are not downloading completely... it is missing some contains.

If some PDF attachment is of size 38 Kb when I am downloading attachment using IE or any other web browser but when I am downloading it using my java code it is of size 37.3 Kb. It is not complete
Hence when I try to open it using Adobe Reader it shows error message that "File is corrupted..."

Here is code I have written to download attachment:

```
public boolean saveFile(String filename,Part part) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    boolean ren = true;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedInputStream fin = null;
    InputStream input = part.getInputStream();

    File pdffile = new File("d:/"+filename);
    try{
        if(!pdffile.exists()){
            fos = new FileOutputStream(pdffile);
            fin = new BufferedInputStream(input);
            int size = 512;
            byte[] buf = new byte[size];
            int len;

            while ( (len = fin.read(buf)) != -1 ) {
                fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            input.close();
            fos.close();
        }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists");
        }
    }catch(Exception e ){
        ren = false;
    }
    return ren;
 }
```

Am I missing something? Any useful help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use [MimeBodyPart#saveFile(File)](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#saveFile(java.io.File)) or the equivalent method taking a String instead? If that fails as well, I would try to contact Bill Shannon (JavaMail developer, he frequents the [JavaMail forum on forums.oracle.com](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=975).

Comment: BTW: It is also helpful to specify which JavaMail version you are using, I remember that with some of the earlier version there were some problems with decoding attachments (skipping bytes) if the BASE64 encoding of pairs was on the boundary of a buffer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes i have already used savefile(File) method of MimeBodyPart but it also fails, it results same(skips some bytes at end), I am using JavaMail 1.4.4. Thanks..

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have found some more information that problem generally occurs when pdf is password protected...but I am not sure as same code segment sometimes works on password protected pdf's too..

Comment: I don't think so, binary data is binary data and for JavaMail it does not (or: should not) matter if it is an image of a cute kitten or a protected PDF.

Comment: If you read the message with another mail program such as Thunderbird, does it save the attachment correctly?  If so, I would need a lot more detail to help debug the problem and determine if it's a bug in JavaMail.  In that case, contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found solution at [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#JAF) Reading Mail, IMAP section
Gmail server is  running bug with attachments

First I tried to set partialfetch property false but sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't

```
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");
```

There is another way listed in FAQ which is just use copy constructor of MimeMessage and store orignal object in some tempmsg and then get content of tempmsg

```
    MimeMessage tempmsg = new MimeMessage(msg);
    Multipart part = (Multipart) tempmsg.getContent();
```

and now perform all operations it should work..

For detailed information about what actually happens goto [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#JAF) Reading Mail, IMAP section you will find all answers..

Comment: Sorry but I could not reproduce your solution. The first line MimeMessage tempmsg = new MimeMessage(msg); doesn't compile for me: Cannot resolve constructor 'MimeMessage(javax.mail.Message)'. What am I doing wrong? What type of object are you passing to the constructor?

Answer (score 5):

Spent a few hours on this and finally figured it out.

```
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
```

did it for me. Almost the same thing as @Shantanu above, but because I was using

```
store = session.getStore("imaps");
```

I needed to use "imap**s**" for the partialfetch as well.

Works like a charm.

Full code below:

```
// Load mail properties
Properties mailProperties = System.getProperties();
mailProperties.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");
mailProperties.put("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");

// Connect to Gmail
Session session = Session.getInstance(mailProperties, null);
store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", -1, "username", "password");

// Access label folder
Folder defaultFolder = store.getDefaultFolder();
Folder labelFolder = defaultFolder.getFolder("mylabel");
labelFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] messages = labelFolder.getMessages();

saveAttachments(messages);
```

...

```
 private void saveAttachments(Message[] messages) throws Exception {

 for (Message msg : messages) {


    if (msg.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
      Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msg.getContent();

      for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
        Part part = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
    String disposition = part.getDisposition();

    if ((disposition != null) && 
       ((disposition.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT) || 
       (disposition.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.INLINE))))) {
        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) part;
        String fileName = mimeBodyPart.getFileName();

        File fileToSave = new File(fileName);
        mimeBodyPart.saveFile(fileToSave);
     }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting empty attachments and `props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false")` did help me as well.